# How to make the active slide grow in height from bottom to top?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to make the active slide grow in height not downwards but upwards? I use owl-carousel

Site http://cb95142.tmweb.ru/

Code jsfiddle.net/90f2cLkm/

My result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKEfI.jpg)

Right
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX5Dk.jpg)

```css
.gallery-slider .owl-item.center img {
  height: 700px !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="gallery-block">
                    <div class="plug"></div>
                    <div class="title-block">
                        <div class="forehead">Frispes gallery</div>
                        <h3>Immersive beautiful<br>co-working space gallery</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-slider owl-carousel">
            <div class="gal-slide">
                <img src="img/gal-1.jpg" alt="1">
            </div>
            <div class="gal-slide">
                <img src="img/gal-2.jpg" alt="2">
            </div>
            <div class="gal-slide">
                <img src="img/gal-3.jpg" alt="3">
            </div>
            <div class="gal-slide">
                <img src="img/gal-4.jpg" alt="4">
            </div>
            <div class="gal-slide">
                <img src="img/gal-5.jpg" alt="4">
            </div>
            <div class="gal-slide">
                <img src="img/gal-6.jpg" alt="4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: The image is quite distorted, is that OK?

Answer (score 1):

If you add this it will do it.

```
padding-top: 100%;
position: relative;
```

So your CSS will become:

```
.gallery-slider .owl-item.center img {
    height: 700px !important;
    padding-top: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

This works because the width of the slides is equal to their height (when not the current one) and padding is always in terms of the x not the y axis. So this code moves the image up by 700px and then down by the normal height due to the padding.

However, a couple of points. The image gets distorted and this is massively noticable on narrow viewports - people look 'stretched'. Also the site is non responsive - perhaps that doesn't matter in your use case but if it does try to work in relative rather than absolute units like px.

Comment: It worked on your site when I put it in via the browser dev tools. Where did you put it?

Comment: I also wrote that code for .gallery-slider .owl-item.center img with the properties you wrote to me. Do you do it exactly as it should - the active slide increases in height over the inactive ones?